# How do I do incremental backups for SQLite?

Tags: c, sqlite, backup, database-backups

I have a program that saves logging data to an SQLite3 database. I would like to back up the database while the program is still running. I have accomplished this by using the SQLite Online Backup API (http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) and it works fine, however it lags the process until the backup is complete...

Does anyone know of a way to do incremental backups in SQLite? I would preferably only backup new data, not the entire database each time I run the backup.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a general purpose solution to your problem.

If your logging data is timestamped and reasonably simple in structure,
you could run a separate process to extract recent data and insert it
into your backup stream.

Answer (score 0):

I made a library named [sqlite3-incremental-backup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3-incremental-backup) (in NodeJS and Python) for this purpose if you want to have a look.